# IE9 CSS issues with hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I'm using the Pure Drawer scripts to generate a slider drawer navigation scheme for an upcoming site (http://advanced1772.inmotionhosting.com/~authenticstoryte/). Works great, but the client wants it to work in IE9 (yea, really....) and on IE9, the hamburger menu looks like it just went through a demolition derby. I think it might be because of the fact it used :before and :after pseudo elements to generate the menu. So is there an alternative method to make this work on IE9. The drawer itself works just great. It's the hamburger icon that's the issue:

HTML

```
<div class="pure-container" data-effect="pure-effect-slide">
<input type="checkbox" id="pure-toggle-right" class="pure-toggle" data-toggle="right">
<label class="pure-toggle-label" for="pure-toggle-right" data-toggle-label="right">
<span class="pure-toggle-icon"></span> </label>
<div class="pure-drawer" data-position="right">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-nav-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://advanced1772.inmotionhosting.com/~authenticstoryte/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-17"><a href="http://advanced1772.inmotionhosting.com/~authenticstoryte/2016/04/25/hello-world/">Hello world!</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="pure-pusher-container">
<div class="pure-pusher">
```

CSS

```
.pure-toggle-label { border: none!important; top: 4px!important; }
.pure-toggle-label .pure-toggle-icon {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -4px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -4px, 0);
}
.pure-toggle-label .pure-toggle-icon, .pure-toggle-label .pure-toggle-icon::before, .pure-toggle-label .pure-toggle-icon::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 4px;
    width: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #5d809d;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: You might just be missing the microsoft specific syntax '-ms-transform: translate3d(-50%, -4px, 0);'

Comment: Get a new client.  Hehe...

Comment: IE9 doesn't support 3D transforms, only 2D.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does IE9 support 3D CSS Transforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427260/does-ie9-support-3d-css-transforms)

Comment: actually copy-pasting the html and css to jsfiddle causes the same issue in other browsers. Are you sure your code is correct? https://jsfiddle.net/j4p4zj37/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with your page in IE9 emulation, I added these:

```
.pure-toggle-label .pure-toggle-icon::after {
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 10px);
}
.pure-toggle-label .pure-toggle-icon::before {
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -14px);
}
```

This will leave the translate3d alone, though it looks like you really only need 2d.

For the transition effects see: [Does IE9 support transition CSS3 effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581081/does-ie9-support-transition-css3-effects)

Comment: Thanks. I got it working although i notice on click, the hamburger is no longer an X but not just two lines with a lot of separation between them.

Comment: Hmm weird, it works great in IE11 with IE9 emulation

Comment: Have a look at the .pure-toggle-icon in another browser. When you see the X, then check the various styles with :checked in it. They're long lists with various css paths. I found 2 that have a transform style. Add that same transform with -ms- prefix. I think that should fix the IE9 X problem.

Comment: Yea, I think I found it. Haven't checked yet on IE9 but I will. Thanks!